# Unterschied zwischen "Körper" und "Leib"

Tags: difference, meaning, noun

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Begriffen *Körper* und *Leib*? Ich meine in dieser Bedeutung (nach dem Duden):

**[Körper](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Koerper)**

```
1. a. das, was die Gestalt eines Menschen oder Tieres ausmacht; 
      äußere Erscheinung eines Menschen oder Tieres, Gestalt; 
      Organismus eines Lebewesens
```

**[Leib](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Leib)**

```
1. a. (gehoben) Körper
   b. (gehoben) äußere Erscheinung eines Menschen, Gestalt
```

Gibt es neben dem Gebrauch (gehoben oder nicht) noch weitere Differenzierungen?

Comment: Leib ist ein sehr altes Wort, das normalerweise in schriftlichen oder religiösen Zusammenhängen verwendet wird.

Answer (score 9):

Duden ist kein Lexikon für Deutschlernende. Lexika, die speziell für Deutschlernende konzipiert sind, müssen, glaube ich, erst noch geschaffen werden. Hier ist uns Englisch mit seinem Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 100 Jahre voraus. 
Duden's Bemerkung "Leib ist gehoben" stimmt nur teilweise und ist nicht sehr präzise. 
Körper ist das normale Wort. Und man müßte genauer untersuchen, wo wir Leib benützen.

1 Wir sagen Oberkörper, aber Unterleib.

2 In religiösen Texten wird oft Leib im übertragenen Sinn gebraucht.

3 Hauptsächlich wird Leib idiomatisch benützt. Das heißt, in vielen feststehenden Redewendungen benützen wir Leib. Sie verbrannte bei lebendigem Leib. Du hast kein Herz im Leib. DWDS gibt einen guten Einblick in solche Wendungen.

http://www.dwds.de/?qu=leib

Der Umgang mit dem Digitalen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache (DWDS) will gelernt sein. Was hier an Material zusammen getragen wurde, ist allerdings phänomenal. Für die Benützung müßte es allerdings einen Kurs geben. Es gibt acht Teile:

1 Lexikonteil mit Worterklärung

2 Etymologisches Wörterbuch. Das ist das Lexikon von Pfeiffer. Scrollbar.

3 Synomymgruppen

4 Wortprofil. Scrollbar.

5-8 Textmaterial (in Unmengen). Alle Felder sind scrollbar.

Die kurze Startseite ist lesenswert.

http://www.dwds.de

Es ist schade, das dieses erstaunliche Informationswerk zur deutschen Sprache keine Einführung für den Beñützer hat.

Answer (score 5):

Ein kleiner Versuch der Differenzierung: 
Leib ist aus dem mittelhochdeutschen "lip" entstanden, das sowohl Leben als auch Leib bezeichnete. Der Körper ist aus dem lateinischen "corpus" entlehnt, das den Körper als auch den Leichnam bezeichnete. 
Dementsprechend lässt sich der Leib als belebter individueller Körper beschreiben, der lebendig und erspürbar und eng mit den Befindlichkeiten und dem Lebensfunken eines Menschen verknüpft ist, während der Körper eher die Materie des Anatomen oder Physiologen beschreibt, die lebendig oder auch tot sein kann.
Der eher ganzheitlich gemeinte Leib ist aus dem alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch ziemlich verschwunden, der leichter einer zergliedernden Weltsicht verbundene "Körper" ist im heutigen Sprachgebrauch üblich.

Comment: Schöne Antwort. Dazu passend: das uralte [Leib-Seele-Problem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophie_des_Geistes#Das_Leib-Seele-Problem).

Answer (score 1):

Die Wörter haben erst einmal keinen Bedeutungsunterschied. „Leib“ ist in der deutschen Sprache das ältere Wort und ist in den meisten Situationen durch das Wort „Körper“, das eine lateinische Wurzel hat, verdrängt worden.